# How to find the average of the difference between the largest and smallest elements in all rows of an 2D array using C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I was given a question to solve in C but I'm confused.

Write a C program which can four cities temperature for last five days and display average of the difference between the highest and lowest temperature of all cities

Sample Input

20 27 28 22

12 22 12 20

22 24 25 33

33 30 30 29

Sample Output

7.75

I've tired to find the differences between the largest and smallest element from each row of an 2D array. But now I'm facing that how can I store the differences from each row and find the average? Here's my piece of code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array1[10][10];
    int num, row, column;

    printf("How many rows and columns are needed: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);

    printf("\nHow many cities temperature you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEnter %d cities temperature: ", num);

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        int largeA = array1[i][0];
        int smallA = array1[i][0];

        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            if(array1[i][j] > largeA)
            {
                largeA = array1[i][j];
            }
            if(array1[i][j] < smallA)
            {
                smallA = array1[i][j];
            }
        }
        unsigned diff = 0u +  largeA - smallA;
        printf("%d\n", diff);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need any arrays of the highest and lowest temperature for each day, or their difference. You only need to store one running total of those differences. Each day, find the lowest and highest, and add their difference to a total. Finally divide that total by the number of days.

Comment: Your example contains four rows, four numbers each, whilst the description says the input should consist of 4×5 values.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create another 1D array that will hold the temperature difference of each city.

The average temperature difference will be the average of this array.

Comment: I'm still confused. Can you enlighten me.